# How to set framerate in ffmpeg for video generated from static image

Tags: video, ffmpeg, type-conversion, jpeg, frame-rate

I'm trying to generate a 5 sec video from a static jpeg file.
I need an 720p .H264 file with 23.976 fps and AAC 44100Hz 192kb for audio (I'm just creating a 5 sec logo to concatenate it with recorded video in this exact format).

So I'm doing this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i logo.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 5 -vf "fps=24/1001" -c:a aac -b:a 192k logo_mov.mp4
```

And I get a tiny resulting file, that doesn't playback at all.
Removing the `-vf "fps=24/1001"` produces a 5 second video, but in 25fps format. How do I set it up correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct fps value is not `24/1001`, you are missing a decimal point. The correct value is `24/1.001` which equals`23.976`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Now having a small glitch between the concatenated videos. Guess i don't have a keyframe on the last frame of the logo_mov.mp4. Is it possible to fix it during generation?

Comment: This is usually written as 24000/1001, but it makes no difference.